# Difference between binary relevance and one hot encoding?

Tags: encoding, data-mining, multilabel-classification, one-hot-encoding

Binary relevance is a well known technique to deal with multi-label classification problems, in which we train a binary classifier for each possible value of a feature:

http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10994-011-5256-5

On the other side, one hot encoders (OHE) are commonly used in natural language processing to encode a categorical feature taking multiple values as a binary vector:

http://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/LectureNotes1.pdf

Can we consider that these two concepts are the same one? Or are there technical differences?

Comment: They look fairly different to me. Why do you think they are closely related?

Comment: If you use binary relevance to encode a dataset having a single label per class, it looks like you are applying one-hot encoding on each instance, the vector would be the concatenation of the binary values for all the labels. In multi-target problems, the concepts are different of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both methods are different.

**1. One-Hot encoding**

In **one-hot encoding**, vector is considered.
[image]

Above diagram represents binary classification problem.

**2. Binary Relevance**

In binary relevance, we do not consider vector. Following diagram represents class label generation using binary relevance method which is using scalar value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is a detailed explanation, including the powerset representation.

Comment: @mountrix for more information you can watch this video (Udacity, Google ->Deep Learning ): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Uyr93f3C2M